# Template Toolkit cannot find template files

Tags: apache, perl, mod-rewrite, routes

I have the following .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/views/.*/.*\.html
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/(.*)$ index.pl?controller=$1&action=$2&id=$3
```

This allows me to forward requests like /Users/show/1 to my main controller. I can also access the template files; at least in my browser i can open the file:

/views/Users/add.html

However when I try to access the file in my controller when i want to render the template, it cannot be found (No such file or directory)

This is the code where i try to render the template:

```
package UsersController;


use Moose;
use Controllers::ControllerRole;
use Template;
with 'ControllerRole';


has 'example' => (
    is => 'rw',
    isa => 'Str',
    default =>'test',
);

sub show {  
    my $self = shift;
    my $id = $self->{params}->{id};

     my $config = {
        INTERPOLATE  => 1,               # expand "$var" in plain text
        POST_CHOMP   => 1,               # cleanup whitespace
        PRE_PROCESS  => 'header',        # prefix each template
        EVAL_PERL    => 1,               # evaluate Perl code blocks
    };

    my $vars = {
        id => $id,
    };

    my $template = Template->new();
    $template->process('views/Users/add.html', $vars) || die "$!";


}

1;
```

I also tried using absolute or relative paths, but apache complained that this is not allowed

It maybe to helpful to see the file structure of my project:

[image]

Update:
If i use `chdir` i can `open` the file with Perl's open function, but trying to process the file i still get the error

> `file error - header: not found`

Here is a second iteration of my code:

```
sub show {  
    my $self = shift;
    chdir '/srv/http/perlweb';
    my $id = $self->{params}->{id};

     my $config = {
        INTERPOLATE  => 1,               # expand "$var" in plain text
        POST_CHOMP   => 1,               # cleanup whitespace
        PRE_PROCESS  => 'header',        # prefix each template
        EVAL_PERL    => 1,               # evaluate Perl code blocks
        ABSOLUTE => 1,
        RELATIVE => 1,
    };

    my $vars = {
        id => $id,
        planet => 'earth',
        captain => 'kirk',
    };

    open my $fh, "views/Users/add.html" or die "$!"; #this works

    close $fh;

    my $tt = Template->new($config);
    $tt->process('views/Users/add.html', $vars) or die $tt->error(); # this does not work

}
```

Comment: Again, did you try setting [`INCLUDE_PATH`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Template#INCLUDE_PATH) anywhere?

Comment: What did you set it to? Did you still get the same error? Did you have `ABSOLUTE` and `RELATIVE` both enabled when you used `INCLUDE_PATH`?

Comment: Where is the `header` file that you're including in the `PRE_PROCESS` config option? AFAICS, that is what TT is complaining about.

Comment: i removed the pre_process option and it worked

Comment: I thought that might be the problem. The Apache set up isn't really relevant -- Template Toolkit works with local files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Template Toolkit has the configuration option `INCLUDE_PATH` that allows you to set up one or more directories in which Template Toolkit looks to find template files. If you set the include_path variable, rather than putting the path in the `$tt->process()` directive, you can then set up paths in a global config and not hardcode paths in every `$tt->process()` directive or have to use the `ABSOLUTE` or `RELATIVE` options. You can specify numerous directories in the `INCLUDE_PATH`, and use a subroutine to generate include paths, so you are not limited to keeping all your templates in a single directory.

I would therefore change the config and process directives to the following:

```
my $config = {
    INTERPOLATE  => 1,               # expand "$var" in plain text
    POST_CHOMP   => 1,               # cleanup whitespace
    PRE_PROCESS  => 'header',        # prefix each template
    EVAL_PERL    => 1,               # evaluate Perl code blocks
    INCLUDE_PATH => [ "/srv/http/perlweb/views/Users/",
                      "/wherever/header/is",
                      \&my_cool_sub_to_generate_a_path_on_the_fly ]
};

my $tt = Template->new($config);
$tt->process('add.html', $vars) or die $tt->error();
```

The documentation on [`INCLUDE_PATH`](http://template-toolkit.org/docs/manual/Config.html#section_INCLUDE_PATH) has full information on options for this setting.

Note that the error you are getting is about the file `header` that is automatically included in each template -- make sure that you have its directory in your `INCLUDE_PATH`.